# How can i resolve EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) in IOS release react native app?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, react-native, compiler-errors

Can anyone assist with how to interpret this crash log? I'm using react native framework to create my app for IOS. The app works in Xcode and if i load it in a fisical device but when I want to release it and load it in Apple store it's crashed. Someone have any idea of what can happen? Thanks.

Here the logs :

```
{"app_name":"ReactListooRest","timestamp":"2019-10-08 13:20:55.03 +0530","app_version":"1.2","slice_uuid":"46b8aafa-3f4b-3e30-9fb7-a99cd31e90a3","adam_id":1464366464,"build_version":"1","bundleID":"io.listooResto","share_with_app_devs":false,"is_first_party":false,"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 13.1.2 (17A860)","incident_id":"0AA01EC3-D14F-4451-B2C8-8AC692A3B862","name":"ReactListooRest"}

Incident Identifier: 0AA01EC3-D14F-4451-B2C8-8AC692A3B862

CrashReporter Key:   f18caf4773ab78f3dd97dbbaaded822efad44208

Hardware Model:      xxx

Process:             ReactListooRest [417]

Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/CD9DD442-01EF-4B05-9CE8-2F22BF7CE1D8/ReactListooRest.app/ReactListooRest

Identifier:          io.listooResto

Version:             1 (1.2)

AppStoreTools:       11A1002b

Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)

Role:                Foreground

Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Coalition:           io.listooResto [556]









Date/Time:           2019-10-08 13:20:54.9412 +0530

Launch Time:         2019-10-08 13:20:54.8435 +0530

OS Version:          iPhone OS 13.1.2 (17A860)

Release Type:        User

Baseband Version:    n/a

Report Version:      104





Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)

Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Triggered by Thread:  0





Application Specific Information:

abort() called





Last Exception Backtrace:

(0x1afe9298c 0x1afbbb0a4 0x1afd88054 0x104fe937c 0x104fe1ae0 0x1b3e96ebc 0x1b3e98c8c 0x1b3e9e4c0 0x1b367a810 0x1b3b0b3ec 0x1b367b2f8 0x1b367ad50 0x1b367b124 0x1b367a9e0 0x1b367eefc 0x1b3a3e028 0x1b3b245ac 0x1b367ec34 0x1b3b244a8 0x1b367eaa0 0x1b34f3efc 0x1b34f2a64 0x1b34f3c34 0x1b3e9c840 0x1b3a5ea0c 0x1b4f2b994 0x1b4f50960 0x1b4f360f8 0x1b4f5061c 0x1afb60184 0x1afb09038 0x1b4f75540 0x1b4f7520c 0x1b4f75734 0x1afe107e0 0x1afe10738 0x1afe0fed0 0x1afe0b01c 0x1afe0a8bc 0x1b9c76328 0x1b3ea06d4 0x104fe1dac 0x1afc95460)





Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Thread 0 Crashed:

0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x00000001afc8aebc 0x1afc66000 + 151228

1   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x00000001afba6790 0x1afba4000 + 10128

2   libsystem_c.dylib              0x00000001afafa824 0x1afa87000 + 473124

3   libc++abi.dylib                0x00000001afc537d4 0x1afc52000 + 6100

4   libc++abi.dylib                0x00000001afc539c4 0x1afc52000 + 6596

5   libobjc.A.dylib                0x00000001afbbb358 0x1afbb5000 + 25432

6   libc++abi.dylib                0x00000001afc60304 0x1afc52000 + 58116

7   libc++abi.dylib                0x00000001afc6029c 0x1afc52000 + 58012

8   libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001afb60198 0x1afb04000 + 377240

9   libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001afb09038 0x1afb04000 + 20536

10  FrontBoardServices            0x00000001b4f75540 0x1b4f1f000 + 353600

11  FrontBoardServices            0x00000001b4f7520c 0x1b4f1f000 + 352780

12  FrontBoardServices            0x00000001b4f75734 0x1b4f1f000 + 354100

13  CoreFoundation                0x00000001afe107e0 0x1afd67000 + 694240

14  CoreFoundation                0x00000001afe10738 0x1afd67000 + 694072

15  CoreFoundation                0x00000001afe0fed0 0x1afd67000 + 691920

16  CoreFoundation                0x00000001afe0b01c 0x1afd67000 + 671772

17  CoreFoundation                0x00000001afe0a8bc 0x1afd67000 + 669884

18  GraphicsServices              0x00000001b9c76328 0x1b9c73000 + 13096

19  UIKitCore                      0x00000001b3ea06d4 0x1b34b0000 + 10421972

20  ReactListooRest                0x0000000104fe1dac 0x104fdc000 + 23980

21  libdyld.dylib                  0x00000001afc95460 0x1afc94000 + 5216





Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.UIKit.KeyboardManagement

Thread 1:

0   libobjc.A.dylib                0x00000001afbbf874 0x1afbb5000 + 43124

1   libobjc.A.dylib                0x00000001afbc9368 0x1afbb5000 + 82792

2   libobjc.A.dylib                0x00000001afbb74fc 0x1afbb5000 + 9468

3   Foundation                    0x00000001b01578c8 0x1b0143000 + 84168

4   Foundation                    0x00000001b037dfe0 0x1b0143000 + 2338784

5   Foundation                    0x00000001b037e428 0x1b0143000 + 2339880

6   Foundation                    0x00000001b0157d8c 0x1b0143000 + 85388

7   UIKitCore                      0x00000001b43c5094 0x1b34b0000 + 15814804

8   Foundation                    0x00000001b037e024 0x1b0143000 + 2338852

9   Foundation                    0x00000001b015770c 0x1b0143000 + 83724

10  Foundation                    0x00000001b039fb34 0x1b0143000 + 2476852

11  Foundation                    0x00000001b03a0144 0x1b0143000 + 2478404

12  Foundation                    0x00000001b01ac6e4 0x1b0143000 + 431844

13  Foundation                    0x00000001b0157438 0x1b0143000 + 83000

14  Foundation                    0x00000001b0156de4 0x1b0143000 + 81380

15  Foundation                    0x00000001b037c6ac 0x1b0143000 + 2332332

16  libxpc.dylib                  0x00000001afa6bd88 0x1afa54000 + 97672

17  libxpc.dylib                  0x00000001afa6001c 0x1afa54000 + 49180

18  libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001afb60204 0x1afb04000 + 377348

19  libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001afb1e0dc 0x1afb04000 + 106716

20  libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001afb0c330 0x1afb04000 + 33584

21  libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001afb0ce88 0x1afb04000 + 36488

22  libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001afb16340 0x1afb04000 + 74560

23  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x00000001afbaffa4 0x1afba4000 + 49060

24  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x00000001afbb2ae0 0x1afba4000 + 60128





Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: E2A75177-A726-43D7-9B9F-3F72422A5636

Thread 2:

0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x00000001afc8b8b0 0x1afc66000 + 153776

1   libsystem_platform.dylib      0x00000001afb9df54 0x1afb99000 + 20308

2   CoreFoundation                0x00000001afd8e580 0x1afd67000 + 161152

3   CoreFoundation                0x00000001afdfb89c 0x1afd67000 + 608412

4   CoreFoundation                0x00000001afdfb134 0x1afd67000 + 606516

5   CoreFoundation                0x00000001afd6b410 0x1afd67000 + 17424

6   CoreFoundation                0x00000001afd8e750 0x1afd67000 + 161616

7   CoreFoundation                0x00000001afec8f88 0x1afd67000 + 1449864

8   Foundation                    0x00000001b023d4c0 0x1b0143000 + 1025216

9   Foundation                    0x00000001b014d514 0x1b0143000 + 42260

10  Foundation                    0x00000001b014c720 0x1b0143000 + 38688

11  AccessibilityUtilities        0x00000001b9d0168c 0x1b9c7c000 + 546444

12  AXCoreUtilities                0x00000001b94dfc38 0x1b94d6000 + 39992

13  libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001afb5f610 0x1afb04000 + 374288

14  libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001afb60184 0x1afb04000 + 377220

15  libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001afb1400c 0x1afb04000 + 65548

16  libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001afb0ced8 0x1afb04000 + 36568

17  libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001afb08628 0x1afb04000 + 17960

18  libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001afb14fd0 0x1afb04000 + 69584

19  libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001afb1579c 0x1afb04000 + 71580

20  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x00000001afbaff64 0x1afba4000 + 48996

21  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x00000001afbb2ae0 0x1afba4000 + 60128





Thread 3:

0   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x00000001afbb2ad8 0x1afba4000 + 60120





Thread 4 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.runningboardservices.background-workloop

Thread 4:

0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x00000001afc695f4 0x1afc66000 + 13812

1   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x00000001afc68a60 0x1afc66000 + 10848

2   libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001afb1b7f8 0x1afb04000 + 96248

3   libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001afb1bbc0 0x1afb04000 + 97216

4   libxpc.dylib                  0x00000001afa5f544 0x1afa54000 + 46404

5   RunningBoardServices          0x00000001b29dcd50 0x1b29b2000 + 175440

6   RunningBoardServices          0x00000001b29dd47c 0x1b29b2000 + 177276

7   RunningBoardServices          0x00000001b29c4f1c 0x1b29b2000 + 77596

8   RunningBoardServices          0x00000001b29c1b68 0x1b29b2000 + 64360

9   AssertionServices              0x00000001b455351c 0x1b4552000 + 5404

10  AssertionServices              0x00000001b4558088 0x1b4552000 + 24712

11  libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001afb5f610 0x1afb04000 + 374288

12  libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001afb60184 0x1afb04000 + 377220

13  libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001afb0e110 0x1afb04000 + 41232

14  libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001afb16340 0x1afb04000 + 74560

15  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x00000001afbaffa4 0x1afba4000 + 49060

16  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x00000001afbb2ae0 0x1afba4000 + 60128





Thread 5 name:  Dispatch queue: AXUpdateQueue

Thread 5:

0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x00000001afc695f4 0x1afc66000 + 13812

1   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x00000001afc68a60 0x1afc66000 + 10848

2   libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001afb1b7f8 0x1afb04000 + 96248

3   libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001afb1bbc0 0x1afb04000 + 97216

4   libxpc.dylib                  0x00000001afa5f544 0x1afa54000 + 46404

5   CoreFoundation                0x00000001afdf9d00 0x1afd67000 + 601344

6   CoreFoundation                0x00000001afd72e00 0x1afd67000 + 48640

7   CoreFoundation                0x00000001afdf9cb4 0x1afd67000 + 601268

8   CoreFoundation                0x00000001afdf9970 0x1afd67000 + 600432

9   CoreFoundation                0x00000001afdf9b7c 0x1afd67000 + 600956

10  CoreFoundation                0x00000001afd77720 0x1afd67000 + 67360

11  CoreFoundation                0x00000001afdfa494 0x1afd67000 + 603284

12  CoreFoundation                0x00000001afd6d57c 0x1afd67000 + 25980

13  CoreFoundation                0x00000001afd6d4c0 0x1afd67000 + 25792

14  CoreFoundation                0x00000001afec6fd4 0x1afd67000 + 1441748

15  CoreFoundation                0x00000001afdfb89c 0x1afd67000 + 608412

16  CoreFoundation                0x00000001afdfb134 0x1afd67000 + 606516

17  CoreFoundation                0x00000001afd6b410 0x1afd67000 + 17424

18  CoreFoundation                0x00000001afd6bd14 0x1afd67000 + 19732

19  CoreFoundation                0x00000001afec96e0 0x1afd67000 + 1451744

20  AccessibilityUtilities        0x00000001b9d008e0 0x1b9c7c000 + 542944

21  AccessibilityUtilities        0x00000001b9d01f74 0x1b9c7c000 + 548724

22  AccessibilitySettingsLoader    0x00000001e3efb2ec 0x1e3ef5000 + 25324

23  AccessibilitySettingsLoader    0x00000001e3efcc44 0x1e3ef5000 + 31812

24  libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001afb5f610 0x1afb04000 + 374288

25  libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001afb60184 0x1afb04000 + 377220

26  libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001afb0c464 0x1afb04000 + 33892

27  libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001afb0ce58 0x1afb04000 + 36440

28  libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001afb16340 0x1afb04000 + 74560

29  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x00000001afbaffa4 0x1afba4000 + 49060

30  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x00000001afbb2ae0 0x1afba4000 + 60128





Thread 6 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread

Thread 6:

0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x00000001afc695f4 0x1afc66000 + 13812

1   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x00000001afc68a60 0x1afc66000 + 10848

2   CoreFoundation                0x00000001afe10068 0x1afd67000 + 692328

3   CoreFoundation                0x00000001afe0b188 0x1afd67000 + 672136

4   CoreFoundation                0x00000001afe0a8bc 0x1afd67000 + 669884

5   Foundation                    0x00000001b014a994 0x1b0143000 + 31124

6   Foundation                    0x00000001b014a874 0x1b0143000 + 30836

7   UIKitCore                      0x00000001b3f3849c 0x1b34b0000 + 11043996

8   Foundation                    0x00000001b027b0b0 0x1b0143000 + 1278128

9   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x00000001afbaf1ec 0x1afba4000 + 45548

10  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x00000001afbb2aec 0x1afba4000 + 60140





Thread 7:

0   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x00000001afbb2ad8 0x1afba4000 + 60120





Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):

    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000000

    x4: 0x00000001afc635d8   x5: 0x000000016ae224c0   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0xffffffffffffffec

    x8: 0x0000000105d65800   x9: 0x00000001afbaab5c  x10: 0x00000001afba6720  x11: 0x000000000000000b

   x12: 0x00000001e592a080  x13: 0x0000000000000001  x14: 0x0000000000000010  x15: 0x0000000000000034

   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006

   x20: 0x0000000000000407  x21: 0x000000016ae224c0  x22: 0x0000000105d658e0  x23: 0x0000000105d658e0

   x24: 0x0000000000001e03  x25: 0x0000000000000001  x26: 0x0000000283a51e08  x27: 0x000000016ae22c90

   x28: 0x000000016ae23af0   fp: 0x000000016ae22420   lr: 0x00000001afba6790

    sp: 0x000000016ae22400   pc: 0x00000001afc8aebc cpsr: 0x40000000

   esr: 0x56000080  Address size fault


EOF

enter code here
```

Comment: Hi Hember, I have a similar problem even on a fresh project. Do you find any way to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Also having this issue, very similar looking trace.

App released 4 weeks ago was fine, attempting to release a new version of our app, only thing we changed was some copy.

Apple reported it crashed on iPad on iOS 13.1.3

React 0.60

Tested on iPhone 7 with iOS 13.1.3 with no issues, which is strange, but we're waiting on a new tablet to test iPad specifically.

Comment: thanks Robsco,  I managed to solve, I had an error in the component "react-native_firebase"

Comment: I have similar issue... got rejected in the apple store. Can you tell me what you did to solve the issue. I too have  firebase analytics included in my react native app. And previous releases were ok.. the moment i included the firebase analytics and released the build the app got rejected with this crash report. @HemberColmenares